# Are the following type of questions allowed?

Tags: discussion

This is based on 2 things:

1. First thrilled that this site is in beta.
2. Too many questions to start asking here about my daily life.

With that said, I wanted to ask if the following are questions allowed on the site:

- Fasting & Fasting Tips
- Food recommendations, preparations and avoided food types
- Food for babies based on a vegetarian or vegan style (For me this one is very important).
- Family lifestyle changes in the way food, exercise and general thinking are gradually changed to a vegetarian / vegan lifestyle.

Comment: Hi Luis; welcome to the site! With so many issues raised in one post, it is going to be difficult to vet what folks say in any detail (i.e. what is being voted on?) You are a formative member of this community like anyone else, so if you feel a subject should be on topic in good faith, I would simply ask your questions and let folks raise the issue if there's a problem. If you have a deeper concern about a particular question or subject on this site, you can certainly raise it here, but a bulleted list of yes/no scopes is too broad to vet *thoughtfully* in this format. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I see no reason why questions about any of those things would not be on-topic here.

- fasting - sure, if it's in some way specific to veg*nism
- food recs, prep and what to avoid - of course!
- food for veg*n babies - yes, very important topic indeed, please ask...
- family lifestyle changes - sounds like lots of potentially good questions in there

Welcome to the site :D

Comment: Food _recommendations_ I'd be a little cautious about. Cooking.SE guidelines might be a good template for ways to limit that (e.g., "I have tofu, what can I cook"  is too broad, or "how to make seitan taste best" is too subjective)...